# Parse Async Calls not updating $scope variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm having trouble with this code, it's not throwing errors right now so I'm not sure what's wrong. What I'm trying to do is get a list of courses from my Parse database and have `$scope.courses` update to be that result when the async call is finished. Right now it enters the `getCourses` code and retrieves the courses from the database just fine, but the promise doesn't seem to be resolved somehow.

```
myApp.factory("coursesService", function($q){

  return {
    getCourses : function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var coursesQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Subject"));

      coursesQuery.find({
        success: function(results){
          deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(error){
          deferred.reject(error);
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }

});

myApp.controller('SignUpController', function($scope, coursesService) {

    coursesService.getCourses().then(function(results){
      $scope.courses = results;
    });

});
```

Again, no error is being thrown right now so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: you need to catch() the error if you want to see the error.

Comment: Please read how to do that in promise way – https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out my issue. Turns out I wasn't updating my view, so all I had to do was add `$rootScope.$apply();` after both my deferred.resolve and deferred.reject lines of code.

Here is my updated factory code.

```
myApp.factory("coursesService", function($rootScope, $q){

  return {
    getCourses : function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      var coursesQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Subject"));

      coursesQuery.find({
        success: function(results){
          deferred.resolve(results);
          $rootScope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(error){
          deferred.reject(results);
          $rootScope.$apply();
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;

    }
  }


});
```

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. Reading the [Testing Paragraph of AJS guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q/#testing) it is said that if the promise is external, it is needed to inform the rootScope that something changed.

Comment: You entered an error in your code. After `error: function(error){` the code should be `deferred.reject(error);`

Comment: One more thing: considering that AJS Promise wraps every error occurring inside it, consider to log some data as checkpoint in order to keep the control.